# Jumper stops at ith height probability

Tags: probability

A high jumper tries to cross the successive heights 1,2,..., n,... We
assumes that the jumps are independent and that the probability of success at height n is equal
at $\frac{1}{n}$. The jumper is eliminated on his first failure. Let X be the height of the last successful jump. For
all n, calculate the probability $p_n$ of the event X = n . Check that $\sum_{n>0}{p_n} = 1$

My Answer is this: Let $R_i$ be the $ith$ position that the jumper passes.

1. "X = n" = $R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3 \cap ...\cap R_n \cap \overline{R_{n+1}}$
2. $p_n = p(X=n) = p(R_1)p(R_2)p(R_3)...p(R_n)(1- p(R_{n+1})) \iff p_n = ( \frac{1}{1} \cdot  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot... \cdot \frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{1}{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n !}- \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$
3. $\sum_{n>0}{p_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\ \sum_{n = 1}^{n} (\frac{1}{n !}- \frac{1}{(n+1)!}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\ (\frac{1}{1!} - \frac{1}{2!}) + (\frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!}) + (\frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{4!}) + ... + (\frac{1}{(n-1)!}- \frac{1}{n!} ) \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\ (\frac{1}{1!}- \frac{1}{n!}) = 1$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: $\sum_{n>0}\left(\frac{1}{n !}- \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right) =\sum_{n>0}\left(\frac{1}{n !}\right) -\sum_{n>1}\left(\frac{1}{n !}\right) = \frac1{1!}$ or $=(e-1)-(e-2)$, both $=1$ since you have absolute convergence

Comment: It is a telescoping series converging to 1

Comment: So we get 1 by computing limits?

Comment: @V_head ... or spot all but one term is subtracted away, or $\sum_{0<n<k}\left(\frac{1}{n !}- \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right) = 1-\frac1{k!} \to 1$ as $k$ increases.  They all work

Comment: The questions is asking for the value of an infinite sum, that by definition involves some limits.

Comment: @Henry I don't understand

Comment: @V_head Do you mean $\sum_{n>0}\left(\frac{1}{n !}\right) -\sum_{n>1}\left(\frac{1}{n !}\right) =\sum_{n=1}\left(\frac{1}{n !}\right)= \frac1{1!}$ as all but one term is subtracted away?

Comment: I forgot brackets, check it again?

Comment: Your claim $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ \left(\frac{1}{n !}- \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right) = 1$$ is definitely wrong!

Comment: Right right, I modified it, now I think it's correct?